# KnockoutJS testing triggering ko.computed in jasmine

Tags: javascript, knockout.js, jasmine, karma-jasmine

I am currently having **ko.computed** in my view model with few dependencies. Writing the Jasmine Test Case to compare the previous value with the current value I am unable to figure out how to trigger ko.computed function.

Below is my ko.computed.

```
ko.computed(function () {
            if (offers.hasError()) {
                model.offers.resetCards(self.offersCards);
            }
        });
```

Is there a way to trigger this?

Answer (score 0):

Your `computed` does not actually return anything, which makes me think you meant to use a `subscribe`:

```
offers.hasError.subscribe(function(newValue) {
  if (newValue) {
    model.offers.resetCards(self.offersCards);
  }
});
```

This can be triggered by changing the value of `hasError` to something new:

```
offers.hasError(!offers.hasError());
```

To get the current value of the computed, call it using `()`:

```
var comp = ko.computed(function() { return "A" });
console.log(comp()); // Prints "A"
```

To keep track of the previous and current value, you can create a `"beforeChange"` subscription. This is how it works:

```js
var obs = ko.observable("Observable");


var computed = ko.computed(function() {
  return "Computed " + obs();
});

computed.subscribe(function(oldValue) {
  console.log("Value before: " + oldValue);
}, null, "beforeChange");

computed.subscribe(function(newValue) {
  console.log("Value after: " + newValue);
  console.log("---------------------");
});


obs("Observable 1");
obs("Observable 2");
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/knockout/3.2.0/knockout-min.js"></script>
```

So if you want to write a test that compares a new to an old value, you could write this:

```js
var obs = ko.observable("Observable");
var computed = ko.computed(function() {
  return "Computed " + obs();
});


var computedOldValue = computed();

// Whenever the computed changes, store its old value
computed.subscribe(function(oldValue) {
  computedOldValue = oldValue;
}, null, "beforeChange");

// To compare the current to the new value:
console.log("Computed has changed: ", computedOldValue !== computed());

obs("TEST");

console.log("Computed has changed: ", computedOldValue !== computed());
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/knockout/3.2.0/knockout-min.js"></script>
```